# Why Am I getting the error "Not a GROUP BY expression"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to get the amount of workers on a project in sql, but the group by part of the query has some error. I have a separete table (workersonprojects) which matches the project id-s with the workers working on it. The query should select everything + the amount of workers on 1 project.

```
SELECT projectid, name, developerleader, consultantleader, projectleader, budget, count(workerid) AS workers
FROM projects
JOIN workersonprojects on (projectid=project)
JOIN workers on (worker=workerid)
GROUP BY projectid;
```

Comment: Because you can only use columns in select, which are in the Group by Statement or in an Aggregation function

Comment: projectid of what? You need tell GROUP BY. projects.projectid

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh: the "general" rule (as in: the SQL standard) extends that to: or all non-grouped columns are functional dependent on the grouping column(s). But unfortunately Oracle does not support that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, most dbms don't support it. And if you follow my "general rule", you'll never go wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cause you are not including all the columns present in select list to your `group by` clause as can be seen from your query `GROUP BY projectid;`. You should change your query like

```
SELECT p.projectid, 
name, 
developerleader, 
consultantleader, 
projectleader, 
budget,
xxx.workers
FROM projects p
JOIN workersonprojects wp on p.projectid= wp.project
JOIN workers w on p.worker= w.workerid
JOIN (select projectid, count(workerid) AS workers
FROM projects
GROUP BY projectid ) xxx ON p.projectid = xxx.projectid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an aggregate function: `COUNT()`. You have to group by all other columns than `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to other answers:

SELECT projectid, name, developerleader, consultantleader, projectleader, budget, count(workerid) AS workers
FROM projects
JOIN workersonprojects on (projectid=project)
JOIN workers on (worker=workerid)
GROUP BY projectid, name, developerleader, consultantleader, projectleader, budget

Answer (score 0):

In group by query  you have to define  'projectid' of which table you want.

```
SELECT workersonprojects.projectid, projects.name, 
projects.developerleader, projects.consultantleader, projects.projectleader,
projects.budget, 
count(workersonprojects.workerid) AS workers
FROM projects
JOIN workersonprojects on 
(workersonprojects.projectid=projects.projectid)
JOIN workers on (workers.worker=workersonprojects.workerid)
GROUP BY workersonprojects.projectid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically for Group BY clause you need to include all the columns in Group by clause which are not used within any Aggregate Function. Here in this case you have SELECTED projectid,name,developerleader,consultantleader,projectleader,budget columns but we have only one column in COUNT() function. So include these columns in SELECT Clause and boom you have a working query.

```
SELECT projectid,
  name,
  developerleader,
  consultantleader,
  projectleader,
  budget,
  COUNT(workerid) AS workers
FROM projects
JOIN workersonprojects
ON (projectid=project)
JOIN workers
ON (worker=workerid)
GROUP BY PROJECTID,
  name,
  developerleader,
  consultantleader,
  projectleader,
  budget;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by with all the given select statement attributes, so give all the attributes you are selecting in the select statement.